# Sum of two dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, sum

how I can sum two dates?

I have two date in this format j h:i:s and I will like to sum them

I found this script but no reference about days and I'm new to this, here is the script, maybe somebody can make the necessary changes.

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Masino Sinaga, http://www.openscriptsolution.com
 * @copyright October 13, 2009
 */

echo sum_the_time('01:45:22', '17:27:03');  // this will give you a result: 19:12:25

function sum_the_time($time1, $time2) {
  $times = array($time1, $time2);
  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
  }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
}

?>
```

Usage:

All that I need is to sum two dates from two task like:
Task 1 will take 1 day 10 hour 20 mins 10 sec
Task 2 will take 3 days 17 hours 35 mins 40 sec

so the result will be the total time between task 1 and two

Comment: Adding two dates doesn't make much sense.  I can't think of any sensible meaning for `today + tomorrow`, for example.  It does make sense to add a date and a duration, yielding a date (`today + 7 days`), or to subtract to dates yielding an interval (`today - yesterday == 1 day`).

Comment: @Daniel: Do you want to sum two dates or two durations?

Answer (score 6):

just convert the dates using strtotime and sum the timestamps, than convert to the date again using date function:

```
$tmstamp = strtotime($date1) + strtotime($date2);
echo date("Y m d", $tmstamp) ;
```

but why would you add two dates in the first place?

Comment: I edit the question, so I hope it's easy to understand. Your code don't work I think, because I get the same values ($tmstamp is the same all the time)

Answer (score 0):

BAsically what they do, is convert hours and minutes into seconds and add those. Then they convert back to hours/minutes.

You simply have to convert days to seconds too:

```
$seconds += $days * 3600 * 24
```

and then convert back:

```
$days = floor($seconds/(3600*24));
$seconds -= $days*3600*24
```