# Formatting Duration From String in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

i want to calculate different dates from sting, string format is `(01:50:30)`,

**For Example:**
**1:** (01:35:00)
**2:** (04:45:50)
**3:** (02:35:36)
**4:** (01:00:00)
**5:** (06:35:47)

How to calculate these stings with date format?

Comment: You can remove "(" then  use `strtotime` function which convert str to unix time

Comment: i add brackets just for explain not use in my code :)

Comment: these are time and not dates, what do you want to achieve ? what have you tried so far ??

Comment: i want to plus this times

Comment: @HalayemAnis thanks for correction :)

Comment: See it http://stackoverflow.com/a/7343534/3631503

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DateTime**

```
<?php

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '12:05:59');
    var_dump($time);
    $time->modify('5 minutes');
    $time->modify('1 hour');
    $time->modify('-30 seconds');
    var_dump($time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to work out the date solely from the times you have provided, you can turn it into a `DateTime` object which will set the current date to today and used the times you provided as the time.

**For example:**

```
$time = '(01:35:00)';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('(' . 'H:i:s' .  ')', $time);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**Will output:**

`2016-01-25 01:35:00`

You can then easily manipulate the `DateTime` object as you need. The full documentation can be found in the PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php